# Is there any connection of topological combinatorics with differential geometry?

Tags: combinatorics, differential-geometry, soft-question

Is there any good applications or connections of topological combinatorics (or Combinatorics in general) in Differential Geometry?

How much intersection is there between these two fields? Are they in any way similar, or are they very far apart in terms of scope? I had just started reading Topological Combinatorics and I am just trying to get an idea of what the subject is about.